# How to find second derivative of $\mathrm{ln}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \mathrm{arctg}\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-function

the function:

$$\mathrm{ln}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \mathrm{arctg}\frac{y}{x}$$

After finding first derivative I have (took $y$ as a complicated func):

$$y' = \frac{x^2}{x^2-yx-y^2}$$

but it does not seem to be correct answer, started to learn implicit funcs just few days ago, can someone give me the proper direction with its derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$\ln (x^2+y^2) = 2\arctan\frac{y}{x}$$ we get on differentiating,
$$\frac{x + yy'}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{1+y^2/x^2} \frac{xy' - y}{x^2}$$
Simplifying, we get 
$$x+yy' = xy' - y$$ ad hence
$$y' = \frac{x+y}{x-y}$$
Differentiate again:
$$y'' = \frac{(1+y')(x-y) - (1-y')(x+y)}{(x-y)^2}$$
Substitute for $y'$ and simplify to obtain
$$y'' = \frac{2(x^2+y^2)}{(x-y)^3}$$

Comment: How did you get rod of square root on $ln$? Should not we put $tan^-1$ to the second power too then?

Comment: $\ln \sqrt{t} = \frac{1}{2}\ln t$ Hence we have $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2) = \arctan(y/x)$. Bring the 2 to the right hand side.

Comment: so we simplify it using logarithmic rules before proceed with derivatives?

Comment: Yes. That is the usual way to simplify complicated expressions involving logarithms.